# if specific filed is empty toggle switch should not be on or off

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

when someone try to verify customer and a specific filed is empty like "classification" so the switch button should show alert message "pls fill the classification first"
not: the button verification works fine.

here is my code

```
   $("#dataTableBuilder_wrapper").on("change", ".verifycus", function () {
        let verified = $(this).is(":checked") ? true : false;
        $.ajax({
            type: "PATCH",
            url: "customers/" + $(this).attr("dataId"),
            data: {verified: verified},
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.verifycus) {
                    if (verified)
                        responseAlert({type: 'success', title: '@lang('main.customer') @lang('sweetalert.verified')'})
                    else
                        responseAlert({type: 'success', title: '@lang('main.customer') @lang('sweetalert.unverified') '})
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                responseAlert({type: 'error', title: '@lang('main.customerverificationfailed')'})
            }
        });
    });
```

what should i do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the conditions like this before you send the ajax call. 
Note: I'm assuming that your classification field have "classification" as it's ID you have to change the ID according to your code.

```
$("#dataTableBuilder_wrapper").on("change", ".verifycus", function () {
    let verified = $(this).is(":checked") ? true : false;
    // Use your id in place of classification
    if($('#classification').val() == '' || $('#classification').val() == undefinded ){
        alert('please fill the classification field');
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "PATCH",
        url: "customers/" + $(this).attr("dataId"),
        data: {verified: verified},
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.verifycus) {
                if (verified)
                    responseAlert({type: 'success', title: '@lang('main.customer') @lang('sweetalert.verified')'})
                else
                    responseAlert({type: 'success', title: '@lang('main.customer') @lang('sweetalert.unverified') '})
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            responseAlert({type: 'error', title: '@lang('main.customerverificationfailed')'})
        }
    });
});
```